# What's the difference between runas.exe and "Run as different user"?

Tags: windows, windows-domain, runas

I'm working with a line-of-business application that needs to be run as a domain user. I have a user that wants to continue using a local account (since not everything can be migrated to a domain user profile), though the computer is domain-joined, so I set up a shortcut that launches a batch file which uses `runas.exe`, which prompts the user for his domain password. The full batch file looks like this:

```
cd \path\to\app
whoami | findstr /i "domain\\"
if errorlevel 1 (
 runas /user:domain\domuser \path\to\app\app.exe
) else (
 app.exe
)
```

(Essentially, it only does `runas` if the user is not currently logged in as a domain user.) I'm not using any other switches on `runas`, but when I try them, `/noprofile` and `/env` don't seem to do anything.

This application launches and displays its initial screen after putting a password into `runas`. (If it's run as a local user, it throws a failure dialog, and that's not happening here.) However, the application then proceeds to misbehave. The bizarre part is that it works fine if I <kbd>Shift</kbd>+right-click it (either that shortcut or the EXE itself) and do the "Run as different user" thing.

I do not have access to this program's source, nor am I at liberty to discuss specifics of it. That's beside the point, though - **what's different between launching it with `runas` and "Run as different user"?**

This is 64-bit Windows 10 Pro, though I also see this problem on Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: I cannot answer the question fully, but verify the use of Environment variables and the domain user's user *profile*. RUNAS can be started with /noprofile or /profile, and also with /env - check RUNAS /?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimentation, I noticed that `runas.exe` always sets the program's startup directory to `System32`, while *Run as different user* sets the starting directing to the folder containing the EXE.

#### Proof

This can be demonstrated by creating a batch file that contains something like:

```
echo %cd%
pause
```

Place it in a folder accessible to all users. If you run it just by double-clicking it in File Explorer, it will show the directory that contains it. It will do the same if you use *Run as different user*. If you open a Command Prompt window there and do `runas /user:otheruser test.bat`, it will fail ("no such file") if `test.bat` doesn't happen to be on the other user's or the system's `PATH`. That's because `runas` starts in `System32`. If you do `runas /user:otheruser \full\path\to\test.bat`, it will start, and display the path to `System32`, because that's its starting directory.

#### Fixing the problem

The program in question does strange things (but doesn't crash) if it doesn't see certain files in its current/starting directory. Update the batch file to use `runas` on a batch file that first `cd`s to the right directory, then launches the program.

Comment: Ben - When you get a chance, take a quick look at my answer on this post as FYI at a minumum at least as such an example (even if not necessarily using to run as a local admin) it may work in your case so the end-users can just click on a shortcut icon rather than needing to put as a batch script with local to execute. http://serverfault.com/questions/734320/allow-standard-user-to-run-program-as-local-admin-without-elevation-prompt/734360#734360

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE Thanks, that's neat. Unfortunately, security needs to be tight (we work with HIPAA-regulated information), but I'll keep your technique in mind.

Comment: Same here with the HIPAA and HITECH data security regulations. I'm not suggesting to use it anywhere there's a need to gain or grant access to any ePHI though--it's more for local software where they programmed it to only work as a local admin and you cannot grant the end-user local admin access. Just for local apps I suppose where there are do data security requirements with this regard. I always follows the data security 1.) data-at-rest 2.) data-in-motion 3.) access controls compliance requirements for the regs with that respect.